# Convert a log line into comma separated fields using logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I am totally new to Logstash. Can anyone please tell me the filter to add to the configuration file, to separate the following log line using Logstash?

"2011/08/10 09:47:23.449598,0.001199,udp,203.136.22.37,15306,  <->,147.32.84.229,13363,CON,0,0,2,317,64,flow=Background-UDP-Established",

I want the above line to return a JSON object like the following:

```
{
TimeStamp: 2011/08/10 09:47:23.449598
Value: 0.001199
protocol: udp
IP: 203.136.22.37
...
}
```

Comment: http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com try you pattern here

Comment: give me 5 minutes, I am working on it.

Comment: @7171u - That's really useful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy below text and write it to your conf file and run logstash. 
It will take input from console and will output to the console in your desired format.

```
input {
   stdin{
   }
}
filter {
        grok {
           match => ["message","%{DATESTAMP:timestamp},%{BASE16FLOAT:value},%{WORD:protocol},%{IP:ip},%{GREEDYDATA:remaining}" ]
        }
}
output {
  stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks

Comment: One more thing. It works well for error-free log lines. But when I have a line like below, it fails. Note that the second field is missing.


2011/08/10 09:51:34.450457,,tcp,213.200.244.217,47908,   ->,147.32.84.59,6881,S_RA,0,0,4,244,124,flow=Background-Established-cmpgw-CVUT


I want to put a default value in there in my output Json object, if a value is missing. how can I do that?

Comment: What default value you want to put?

Comment: let's say 100 for an example?